# How to display date in a week on ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, date

I have this:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
String dateStr = curFormater.format(date);

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String [] {dateStr}));
```

But it only displays once, I want to make it into listview.  Aany ideas? Thx.

Comment: Well, instead of hardcoding the dateStr into the adapter (`new String [] {dateStr}`), try creating an array of strings with the dates that you want to display?

Comment: Hmm, yes and I want to display it into listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
String[] dateStringArray = new String[7];

for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
    dateStringArray[day] = curFormater.format(date.getTime());
    date.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, true);
}
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dateStringArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm  not sure why you would want a list view of just one date, however, your problem seems to be the understanding of using an ListView, for example your array has one item, as in my first example

```
String[] = {"hello"};
```

This will just show one item in the list view, as in your example

```
String[] = {"hello","how","are","you"};
```

Will show 4 lines, if you want to show the same date multiple times, you could possibly create an array like

```
int x = 5;

String[] print = new String[x];

for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
   print[i] = date;
}
```

This will print out 5 lines of date

Comment: I'm sorry, do what? your question makes no sense

Comment: show the date in different, so if Okt 27, 2011, then Okt 28, Okt 29, etc

Comment: try making an ArrayList<Date>

Answer (score 0):

The array contains just one item:

```
...new String [] {dateStr}...
```

You can easily test the result doing:

```
...new String [] {dateStr,dateStr,dateStr,dateStr,dateS}...
```

then build the array with the dates you want to show.

Comment: but it is not show different date, all of them are same, how to make it different

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to be a bit more descriptive and elaborate on what it's really that you're after. I assume that by now you've figured out how to add multiple entries to a list, based on the answers already given.

To fill your list with subsequent dates, simply get a Calendar instance and create a loop incrementing the day field by 'one' with every step. Something like:

```
List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
for (int i=0; i<31; i++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
    dateList.add(curFormater.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dateList));
```

That should show you today plus the next 31 days in a list.

//edit: yuck, missed MisterSquonk's reply, which covers a similar approach...